# Opening a Hyper-V VM to the Outside World

Tags: windows, networking, routing, hyper-v

I created a Windows Server 2016 virtual server using Hyper-V Manager on the host. I have several virtual machines. The host computer has 2 network connections to our main switch: a dual bonded 10G connection and a dual bonded 1G connection. Between the switch and the outside world is our firewall and the router. Our internal network should not be open or accessible, out host server, or any other virtual computer running on the host. We have a static IP and only need one port open to our VM.

I saw [this SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/713778/hyper-v-host-with-one-external-ip-address-how-do-i-assign-guest-vms-an-internal) question.

I installed RRAS on the host, however the accepted answer was a bit confusing about what to do next. Yes, I know that I need to configure one of the interfaces as a NAT in RRAS, which I did (1 GB). I also need to open up the appropriate port.

1. I only see the 10 GB connection in the drop down list, not the 1G.
2. The IP address of the VM client is the same as the host. How do I assign a unique IP? Furthermore, I presume that I should place the VM on a separate sub-net.
3. As we are talking about a VM off of the host, what changes need to be made on the switch and on the firewall?
4. Anything else?

[image: Hyper-V Manager VM Network Settings]

Here is the RRAS, not that I really configured anything yet.

[image: RRAS]

**UPDATE**

I am leaving the original question for a paper trail of sorts. The question thanks to joeqwerty should have been phrased as such:

`What changes do I need to do, if any, on the VM or the host to get HTTP/HTTPS REST communication flowing based on that port to that VM?`

I guess that I do not need any unique IP or anything special. I just need port 9000 traffic to flow (route) to the VM and only to the VM. As such, what changes need to be made and where?

Comment: You probably don't need to use RRAS at all. How do you need to expose this VM to the outside? Via HTTP/HTTPS, RDS, SMTP, etc.?

Comment: @joeqwerty The request is HTTP/HTTPS REST communication. Specifically port 9000 should get through to and only to the VM from the outside world. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only see the 10 GB connection in the drop down list, not the 1G.

Did you create a Hyper-V Virtual Switch with the 1GB NIC? If not, that's why you don't see it. You need to create a Hyper-V Virtual Switch with the 1GB NIC.

> The IP address of the VM client is the same as the host. How do I
>   assign a unique IP? Furthermore, I presume that I should place the VM
>   on a separate sub-net.

You need to assign the VM a unique ip address. You do that in the OS of the VM. You do this the same way you do in a physical machine. Additionally, you probably don't need to place the VM in a different subnet, but only you know how your network is configured so we can't answer that for you.

> As we are talking about a VM off of the host, what changes need to be
>   made on the switch and on the firewall?

You probably don't need to make any changes on your switch, but again, we don't know your network so only you can answer that. As for the firewall, you'll need a NAT statement and a firewall rule for the VM and for the traffic you want to "forward" to the VM from the outside.

Comment: @joequerty Based on your comments, I might not need to create a unique IP address or do anything special with the networking. The real question, then becomes what changes do I need to do, if any, on the VM or the host to get HTTP/HTTPS REST communication flowing based on that port to that VM?

Comment: The technical solution was: 1) Assign an IP address inside the VM and then reserve that IP address in the DHCP server. 2) Open up the port in the VM firewall manager. 3) Go to the firewall box and add in a new access rule to allow access to that IP. 4) Restrict the VM from accessing anything outside the box. 5) Create a service that will respond to REST calls.